# Troubleshoot MCP23017 and LEDs

Tags: i2c, led

Anyone have any tips to help troubleshoot turning a simple LED on connected through the MCP23017?

- I've installed i2c-tools, and smbus.
- Nothing in my blacklist.conf
- Added i2c-dev to /etc/modules.
- Wired up the same as this [tutorial](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/07/how-to-use-a-mcp23017-i2c-port-expander-with-the-raspberry-pi-part-1/) which is the same as Adafruits
- Shows at 20 using `i2cdetect -y 1`
- 99.9% sure the wiring is correct. (all done on a breadboard, so no solder to go wrong)
- have tried 2 different chips, very doubtful its the chip itself

I've tried Adafruit's python scripts/libraries which run but nothing happens. Also have tried the following:

```
i2cset -y 1 0x20 0x00 0x80
i2cset -y 1 0x20 0x14 0x01
```

Nothing I do can get the light to turn on. I dont know a lot of whats happening with i2cset, is there a place I can look to see if its actually writing? After entering the command theres no feedback, just next line.
Image of wiring, hopefully you can see what you need from it. The chip on the right isn't wired up.
[image]

Comment: The fact that it appears on the bus is 99% of the battle.  I suspect your connections.  Could you post a photo?  Are you powering from 3V3 or 5V?  My [piscope](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) will let you view the bus activity.

Comment: 3v. I'll work on a photo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a quick look through [breadboards](http://www.instructables.com/id/Breadboards-for-Beginners/).

The problem appears to be having the LEDs leads and resistor all connected in rank 23.  All the 5 holes of each rank are connected together (but not to the same numbered rank on the other side of the board).

A solution is to move the non ground lead of the resistor and the cathode lead of the LED into rank 15 which is the only unused rank on your breadboard.